# Post method not working with micronaut framework

Tags: api, kotlin, postman, endpoint, micronaut

I am quite new to micronaut and endpoint concepts however I was curious about something. My get method works and returns what is expected, however, when I use postman to test my post method, I get a 405 method not allowed error. I realise I probably am not using the post method correclty but I am Im not quite sure how to go about properly utilising post. Below is my code

```
 @Controller("/test")
    class Controller {
        @Get
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        fun index(): String {
            return "Its working"
        }
    
        @Post
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        fun dopost(): String{
            return "ok"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/testtestmnpost.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/testtestmnpost/blob/ba1ecd3099e91a9f87112a1bd7df1ec113bfc055/src/main/kotlin/testtestmnpost/Controller.kt

```kotlin
package testtestmnpost

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces

@Controller("/test")
class Controller {
    @Get
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    fun index(): String {
        return "Its working"
    }

    @Post
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    fun dopost(): String{
        return "ok"
    }
}
```

Both of those are working:

```
 $ http :8080/test     
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 6 Nov 2020 16:26:35 GMT
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 11
content-type: text/plain

Its working

 $ 
 $ http POST :8080/test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 6 Nov 2020 16:26:40 GMT
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 2
content-type: text/plain

ok
```